# A CONCEPTUAL QUESTION ABOUT PROBABILITY INFERENCE

Tags: soft-question

Suppose two  continuous random variables $X,Y$ satisfy
$$ X \leq Y$$ and the cdf $F(y)$ of $Y$ is known so that for  a number $c\in [\min Y,\max Y]$
$$P(Y \leq c)=F(c).$$Since $X \leq Y$,can we logically conclude that $X$ is less than  c with probability $F(c)$?Or should we coclude that $P(X \leq c) \geq F(c)? $.Thanks for any clarifications

Comment: Only $P(X \leq c) \geq F(c)$ can be concluded.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer could you please explain a bit as to why

Comment: What do you mean with $c\in [\max Y,\min Y]$?

Comment: Take $X=0,Y=1$ and $c=\frac 1 2$. for a counter-example.

Comment: @drhab ,thank you for pointing it out ,I made the edit

Comment: But how do you know that random variable $Y$ indeed has a minimum and a maximum? Beware that $Y$ is actually a function and its range could be $\mathbb R$. In that case minimum and maximum both lack.

Comment: Thank you again.In my problem Y has a finite range.I should have mentioned that